# why this query always return that the table is booked?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

```
drop procedure if exists AddValidBooking;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE AddValidBooking(IN booking_date DATE, IN table_number INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE booked BOOLEAN;

    START TRANSACTION;
    
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Bookings
        WHERE DATE(Booking_Date) = DATE(booking_date) AND Table_Number = table_number
    ) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END INTO booked;


    IF booked THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        SELECT CONCAT("table ", table_number, " is booked - booking canceled") AS booking_status;
    ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT("table ", table_number, " is free - booked successfully") AS booking_status;
        INSERT INTO Bookings (Booking_Date, Table_Number) VALUES (booking_date, table_number);
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;


CALL AddValidBooking('2023-11-7', 2);
```

It alwyas return table 2 is booked although it is free
I tried many combinations of dates with table numbers and it still returning the same result

Comment: Don't give parameters the same name as columns.

Answer (score 1):

It says [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html) that

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If
> an SQL statement, such as a `SELECT ... INTO` statement, contains a
> reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same
> name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a
> variable.

You could change your query to:

```
WHERE DATE(Bookings.Booking_Date) = DATE(booking_date) AND Bookings.Table_Number = table_number
```

Or better, change the name of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a leading underscore on proc arguments and local `DECLAREd` variables.  That avoids confusion in `Table_Number = table_number`.  Note that case-folding applies; so that test is always 'true'.  (Frankly, I don't know whether it is using the proc arg or the table column!)

If `Bookings.Booking_Date` is declared `DATE` (which it should be), then don't bother using the `DATE()` function.  Ditto for the argument `_booking_date`.  Note:  The string `'2023-11-7'` works fine as a `DATE` literal.

```
DECLARE booked BOOLEAN;
SELECT ... EXISTS(...) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END INTO booked;
IF (booked) THEN
```

Can be simplified

```
IF (EXISTS(...)) THEN
```

That avoids `booked` and `TRUE`/`FALSE` from a function (`EXISTS()`) that already returns true/false.